# Sending appropriate data to production or development with Heap Analytics Web

Tags: heap-analytics

While using heapanalytics.com HTML snippet for analytics, I want to automatically detect which development environment I am in, and use my appropriate key.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.heap=window.heap||[],heap.load=function(e,t){window.heap.appid=e,window.heap.config=t=t||{};var r=t.forceSSL||"https:"===document.location.protocol,a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=(r?"https:":"http:")+"//cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-"+e+".js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(a,n);for(var o=function(e){return function(){heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},p=["addEventProperties","addUserProperties","clearEventProperties","identify","removeEventProperty","setEventProperties","track","unsetEventProperty"],c=0;c<p.length;c++)heap[p[c]]=o(p[c])};
  heap.load("1234567");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline host detection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.heap=window.heap||[],heap.load=function(e,t){window.heap.appid=e,window.heap.config=t=t||{};var r=t.forceSSL||"https:"===document.location.protocol,a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=(r?"https:":"http:")+"//cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-"+e+".js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(a,n);for(var o=function(e){return function(){heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},p=["addEventProperties","addUserProperties","clearEventProperties","identify","removeEventProperty","setEventProperties","track","unsetEventProperty"],c=0;c<p.length;c++)heap[p[c]]=o(p[c])};
  if (location.host.indexOf("localhost") !== -1) {
    heap.load("123456"); // Dev
  } else {
    heap.load("654321"); // Prod
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach for my React web app that uses Vite:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.heap=window.heap||[],heap.load=function(e,t){window.heap.appid=e,window.heap.config=t=t||{};var r=document.createElement("script");r.type="text/javascript",r.async=!0,r.src="https://cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-"+e+".js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(r,a);for(var n=function(e){return function(){heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},p=["addEventProperties","addUserProperties","clearEventProperties","identify","resetIdentity","removeEventProperty","setEventProperties","track","unsetEventProperty"],o=0;o<p.length;o++)heap[p[o]]=n(p[o])};

      if ("%VITE_APP_MY_ENV%" === "myenv-dev") {
        heap.load("1234567890");
      } else if ("%VITE_APP_MY_ENV%" === "myenv") {
        heap.load("1234567891");
      }
    </script>
```